# Urgent answer needed!

Tags: environmental-economics

I am currently studying in 12th. We have a subject called EVS - Environmental Studies. So as usual, we have to do projects. I chose "Bad effects of Plastic".

In the project book I have to write that why I chose this project.

I have to write 10 points in one sentence. Help me!

Comment: Welcome to Economics SE! We have a policy regarding homework questions where we require that you show some work before an answer is provided. More on this topic [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/economics-se-policy-on-homework-questions).  Also, could you clarify why you consider your question relates to economics as "bad effects of plastic" could also relate to physics / chemistry / environment.

Answer (score 1):

Plastic is particularly harmful as it is a trendy topic, so students tend to choose it even when they have do not know what to write about it.

In case the effort barrier to actually read about the subject cannot be overcome, plastic may result in bad grades.

Comment: Although I oftentimes don't like how you (mis-)treat users, this answer was funny and spot on (+1).

Comment: @IñakiViggers I appreciate the sentiment.